Почему при наследовании получаются два разных результата от вида доступа к свойству?
Есть простой код:
class Test {
    private $var;
    
    public function setMe($value) {
        $this->var = $value;
    }
    
    public function getMe() {
        return $this->var;
    }
}

class More extends Test {
    public $var;
}


$oTest = new Test;
$oMore = new More;

$oTest->setMe('foo');
$oMore->setMe('bar');
var_dump($oMore->var);
echo $oMore->getMe();
echo $oTest->getMe();

Результат вывода будет: NULL bar foo
Вопрос: почему при обращении к свойству $oMore->var там NULL, а при доступе через метод getMe - там значение bar, которое пытались установить через setMe? Ведь логично было бы иметь либо NULL и там и там, либо bar. Не понимаю логики.
И почему при $oMore->var значение NULL? Почему наследник не использует в этом случае сеттер для установки значения в свойство своего класса?

Не знаю в общем понятно ли будет, но приватное свойство $var из класса Test недоступно напрямую в классе More, потому $oMore->var ссылается на публичное свойство $var класса More, которое инициализировано как NULL. При вызове же методов setMe и getMe они работают с приватным свойством родителя, поэтому через getMe() вы получаете bar.

@Simon наверное для ТС ещё надо рассказать, почему геттер и особенно сеттер ставят значение у родителя,  а не наследника) хотя вроде по логике наследования ссылка должна вести на текущий объект

Да, всё верно, мне не понятна ситауация. Особенно, если у родительского класса поставить protected, то всё начинает работать как надо. То есть методы начинают ставить значения именно в наследника. Как? Почему?

@AntonS. Потому что когда Ваше свойство protected, дочерний класс может напрямую обращаться к нему, и методы дочернего класса также будут работать с этим свойством. Если же свойство private, дочерний класс его "не видит" и не может с ним взаимодействовать напрямую, что ведет к созданию своих новых свойств с таким же именем, если они объявлены в дочернем классе. Фактически получается что разница в поведении, заключается в уровне доступа к свойству.

Сеттер и геттер в Вашем примере работают с приватным свойством $var родительского класса Test, потому что они были определены в этом классе и не знают о публичном свойстве $var дочернего класса More так как родитель не имеет доступа к свойствам своих дочерних классов. Таким образом получается что, приватное свойство $var инициализируется и используется методами родителя, а публичное свойство $var дочернего класса остается таким же как и было и имеет значение NULL, пока не будет установлено напрямую.

"@Simon Простите, я всё равно ничего не понимаю. Если в setMe написать echo $this::class, то он покажет More, то есть контекст - это класс More. Наследование для того и создано, чтобы класс наследник мог использовать методы родителя.
И вот получается: наследник использует метод родителя, $this в методе setMe ссылается на More, но при этом $this->var относится к Test, а не к More. Confused)

$this всегда указывает на текущий объект, будь то экземпляр родительского или дочернего класса, но вот уже доступ к свойствам через $this->var в методах ограничивается контекстом класса, где метод определен. В случае приватных свойств метод работает только с теми свойствами, которые были объявлены в его классе. Приватные свойства не наследуются, и методы родительского класса всегда работают с приватными свойствами родителя, если таковые имеются, даже если вызываются на объекте дочернего класса.

Вот и получается, что в последнем Вашем примере $this::class выводит More, что верно так как Вы вызываете метод в экземпляре класса More, но несмотря на то, что $this указывает на экземпляр More, $this->var внутри метода setMe обновляет приватное свойство $var в классе Test, так как метод setMe был определен в классе Test, и он будет работать с его приватными свойствами.
